# Run typescript build with tsconfig-paths using pm2

Tags: javascript, typescript, deployment, pm2, tsconfig-paths

I am trying to run the build (.js files) of typescript with the tsconfig-paths in production, I have no problem running typescript with paths. Just when running the build on production with pm2.

I have tried:

```
apps: [
{
  name: 'app',
  script: './dist/index.js',
  node_args: '-r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register',
},
```

],

Comment: Please update your question with the specific errors/problems you're running into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: If as I assume you run info *the* common misunderstanding about tsconfig you may try:

```json
{
  apps: [
  {
    name: 'app',
    script: './dist/index.js',
    node_args: '-r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register',
    env: {
      "TS_NODE_BASEURL": "./dist"
    }
  },
}
```

Explanation:

Typescript allows us to specify path aliases so that we don'y have to use ugly relative paths like `../../../../config`. To use this feature typically you would have a `tsconfig.json` like this:

```json
...
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "baseUrl": "./src", /* if your code sits in the /src directory */
   "paths": {
     "@/*": ["*"]
   }, 
...
```

Now you can do the following:

```
import config from "@/config";
```

It will compile without errors. During the compilation the requested modules are in the `src` directory. However:

```sh
$ node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/index.js
Failure! Cannot find module '@/config'
```

Why is that? Because at runtime config no longer sits inside `./src` but instead can be found in `./dist`.

So how do we handle this?
Fortunately tsconfig-paths allows us to override baseUrl with `TS_NODE_BASEURL` env:

```sh
$ TS_NODE_BASEURL=./dist node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/index.js
Success!
```